# Is it allowed to Center crop admob native content ad image?

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

Am implementing admob native content ad in my android app.
Is it allowed to Center crop admob native ad image?

Here is some documentations i found.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240809

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6329638

which says

Image elements

1. Publishers are allowed to scale the image down without modifying the aspect ratio.
2. Publishers are allowed to crop the image symmetrically by up to 20% in only one dimension (height or width).

Can i use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns AdMob policies and guidelines, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: oh sorry. i want to know can i set scaletype centercrop which is actually a code part.

Comment: Your question is asking if you're _allowed_ to do that, not _how_ to do that. That is not a programming question.

Comment: But I was referred here by [company] for support! 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company/255746#255746

Comment: "Yes. For your on-topic, programming-related questions. For your questions having specifically to do with writing code for their API. But for questions that involve customer service issues, you need to contact the company directly." – Again, this is a question about their policies, not about how to accomplish something through code.

Comment: ok sorry for my mistake. Unfortunately there is no direct contact for admob.